# Using CMU's Pocketsphinx with a small set of words

Tags: linux, performance, speech-recognition

I want to use CMU pocket sphinx for recognizing between a small set of words. I created a corpus for them and created the model files here - http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html.

Now when I run the pocketsphinx_continuous executable with this model on my 12 core Linux machine, it takes about 5 seconds to recognize each word.

1. Is this library usually this slow or am I doing something wrong?
2. the console output shows that it is still searching and evaluating a large number of words where as the size of my model is only 12 words.
3. Is there any other lightweight and easy to use library which I can use for this simple task of disnguishing between about 12-15 words.